# Blank audio recording hack causes huge file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background-process, avaudiorecorder

To keep my iPhone app active in background at all times, I am using the audio recording hack where I start an audio recording session when app resigns foreground. This works fine but there are two concerns:

1. If it goes over several hours, the recorded audio file size will be huge and that will cause storage issues. I tried stopping and starting recording every few seconds but that does not work since app deactivates in background, as soon recording stops. Is there a better way to deal with this issue?
2. What would be the ideal audio recording settings/format for this recording, which will least stress the CPU, Battery and memory?

Comment: Why are you trying to keep the app active in the background constantly? This would just irritate people most likely, as it would destroy battery life.

Comment: @EBrown I need to be able to continuously analyze core motion data in background. I can only do that if the app is active in the background. Of course battery is an issue, hence the question.

Comment: Having your app active in the background constantly **will** kill the battery, no reasonable person would want to use that. If you still plan to do so, try starting another recording session before you kill the current one, to make sure there are no gaps in the timeline.

Comment: @EBrown Actually a number of apps are running in our iPhone background at all times. All VoIP apps for example are always active. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I know, which is why when I had an iDevice I could never run Skype, due to the fact that it destroyed my battery. (Without Skype it was 20+ hours, with Skype it was below 6.) Doing things like this will almost certainly irritate users.